# Shared Crosshair Highlighting /w Non-sequential Series

Tags: highcharts

I have two lines of date data. One line plots a point sequentially every day. The other line plots non-sequental points that fall on one of the days of the previous line.

The problem is that the crosshair functionality behaves weirdly when I do this. See the example linked below. You will notice that although the tooltip and point highlighting shows for the proper point, the crosshair gets stuck on the non-sequential point along the x-axis, even though this is not the current position of my mouse on the chart. The exception to this is when you hover your mouse directly across the line. The crosshair follows the mouse properly then.

See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/2H9m3/1/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            crosshairs: true
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: "datetime", maxPadding: 0, minPadding: 0
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Line',
            data: GenerateData(10, 50)
        }, {
            name: "Events",
            color: "#EF4B68",
            lineWidth: 0,
            marker: {
                enabled: true,
                symbol: "triangle",
                radius: 6
            },
            data: [
                [5 * 86400000, 0],
                [21 * 86400000, 0]
            ]
        }]
    });
});

function GenerateData(min, max) {
    var data = [];

    for (i = 0; i < (30 * 86400000); i = i + 86400000) {
        data.push([i, GetRandomInt(min, max)]);
    }

    return data;
}

function GetRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

I am not sure if this is a bug or something that I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is subtle. It is actually caused by the fact that the `tooltip` is linked over the top-most series. Since you are creating your linear series first then your non-sequential series the top-most series is the 2 points. So, in order to recapture the 'tooltip` and your crosshair you have to hover closer to the series that is behind the non-sequential series.

Fixes:

1. Make the non-sequential series the first one you add.
2. Give an index value to whichever series you want on top that is larger than the least-full series.

I went with option 2:

```
 series: [{
            name: 'Line',
            index: 1,
            data: GenerateData(10, 50)
        }, {
            name: "Events",
            index: 0,
            color: "#EF4B68",
            lineWidth: 0,
            marker: {
                enabled: true,
                symbol: "triangle",
                radius: 6
            },
            data: [
                [5 * 86400000, 0],
                [21 * 86400000, 0]
            ]
        }]
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/2H9m3/2/).

Comment: This is what I thought the problem was. This fix still has a gap. If you mouse into the graph from the bottom in between the two Event points, it still sticks the crosshair to either event, essentially highlighting that invisible line as the active series.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work properly still. Mouse into the chart from the bottom in-between the two event points: http://jsfiddle.net/2H9m3/4/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in new crosshairs core.

Reported to devs: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2816

Thanks!